# I don't know how to create this table html5

Tags: html

it's a project for my school and I'm stuck. I don't know how to solve it. I apologize for the poor image quality; you can write anything to replace what it says. I would appreciate the help.

I hope to receive some help. I have only made simple HTML tables, but I can't do this one. I've been trying all day, but I just can't make progress, and I need to submit this HTML table soon.

[image]

Comment: Then show us what you have got so far.

Comment: I think what you're after is [rowspan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th#rowspan) and [colspan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th#colspan)

Comment: Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please edit the question and how us your attempt.  Then someone can tell you how to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code adjust the text and colors according to your needs

```css
/* CSs */
table{
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th{
  background-color:gray;
}
td,th{
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  padding:10px 20px;
}
.bg-gray{
 background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<table >
  <tr>
    <th align=center rowspan="3">
      Heading
    </th>
    <th colspan="3">
      Poblacon
    </th>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" class="bg-gray">
        send
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" class="bg-gray">
        Total
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bg-gray">
      heading1
    </td>
    <td class="bg-gray">
      heading2
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>abc</td>
  <td>22</td>
  <td>22</td>
  <td>33</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>abc</td>
  <td>22</td>
  <td>22</td>
  <td>33</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>abc</td>
  <td>22</td>
  <td>22</td>
  <td>33</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Total</td>
  <td>22</td>
  <td>22</td>
  <td>33</td>
</tr>

  
  
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example of using table in html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>HTML Table Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 1, Cell 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 2, Cell 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 3, Cell 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This may solve your problem.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mb-10 ">
        <br>
    <table  class="table table-bordered mt-10">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">Title 1</td>
                <td colspan="3">Title 2</td>              
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Title 3</td>               
                <td rowspan="2">Total</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sub Title 1</td>
                <td>Sub Title 2</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>ASDF</td>
                <td>ASDF</td>
                <td>ASDF</td>
                <td>ASDF</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ASDF</td>
                <td>ASDF</td>
                <td>ASDF</td>
                <td>ASDF</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ASDF</td>
                <td>ASDF</td>
                <td>ASDF</td>
                <td>ASDF</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table></div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: its gonna  be better if u give some text-align center

Comment: A code only answer is not as helpful as one which also  describes what the problem was with the original code (you need to wait for the OP to show us this) and how the new code solves it. Also helpful if you make your code into a runnable snippet.